# gnuplot boxes with labels needed

Tags: gnuplot

Im trying to draw a simple gnuplot bar chart. With labels on top of each bar.

this is my test.out

```
279 2 10149
286 1 699999
295 3 14098
```

and this is my command:

`echo "set terminal dumb size 70,30; plot 'test.out' using 3:xtic(1) with boxes" | gnuplot`

It draws a boxes. I want also  labels on top of each.

Please help )

Comment: Plot again `with labels`, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911722/2604213

Comment: Im having troubles when I use with labels. maybe because my xaxis has function xtic(1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must plot the data again `with labels`.

To get the correct x-positions, you must know that in your plot command `plot 'test.out' using 3:xtic(1) with boxes` the x-position is implicitely taken as the row number.

Also, when plotting `with labels` it is best to explicitely format the label string. Using only a column may or may not work and can give quite surprising results, depending on your data.

So, to be short:

```
plot 'test.out' using 0:3:xtic(1) with boxes,\
    '' using 0:3:(strcol(3)) with labels offset 0,1
```

This plots the string content of column 3 as label at position (rownumber, value from column 3), shifted by 1 character height in y-direction.