# gnuplot: add values above bar graphs

Tags: gnuplot

my gnuplot script plot bar graphs in the following 2D format:
[image]

using the following sctipt:

```
set term pngcairo size 800,600
set termoption noenhanced
set title "$file_name" font "Century,22" textcolor "#b8860b"
set tics font "Helvetica,10"
#set xtics noenhanced
set ylabel "Fraction, %"
set xlabel "H-bond donor/aceptor, residue"
set yrange [0:1]
set ytics 0.1
set grid y
set key off
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid 0.5
plot '<cat' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
```

In order to add values above the bars, I've tried to modify it to

```
plot '<cat' using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,1
```

but the values were not added to the bars, with the following warning

```
"/dev/fd/63" line 17: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Y-value on bar graph in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472052/y-value-on-bar-graph-in-gnuplot)

Comment: I've tried to follow it adding the line to the plot command but it did not work for my case ..

Comment: So, what is the question, where is the question mark? What "did not work" mean? What is the error message? What is the graph output?

Comment: I've just indicated what did not work for my case

Answer (score 1):

I can only test for Windows, but I assume `cat` under Linux is the equivalent for `type` under Windows.

So, what is your filename? I would say your filename is simply missing. Check `help piped-data`.

Something like the following should work:

```
plot '<cat myDataFile.dat' using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,1
```

But then, what is the difference to using directly the filename?

```
plot 'myDataFile.dat' using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,1
```

Comment: No actually I've already tried using 0:2:xtic(1) with boxes, '' u 0:2:2 w labels offset 0,1 and it does not work with the warning indicated in the first message :-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight what is your filename? To my knowledge `cat` prints a file to STDOUT.

Comment: @JamesStarlight this problem maybe solved as well?